# In Google Docs, how to make a column with several numbers in each cell sortable?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I am making an expenses spreadsheet in Google Docs and I need to list the numbers of the attachments for each entry. Sometimes this is just one number, sometimes it is several.

I can make this column be formatted as text, but I want to make the spreadsheet sortable by the first attachment number listed. When the cell contents are "1", "2&3", "4-7" etc. "11" is sorted before "2", which is a problem.

The one solution I see is writing the numbers instead as "001", "002&003", "004-007" etc. and still formatting as text, but this strikes me as unnecessarily cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

*Changed the formula to accept the ampersand as well*

The following formula will create a sorted column:

`=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(INDEX(SPLIT(A:A;"-&"),0,0))))`

See example file I've created: [Sort-able text column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdGphcWhINWxTZTFBX0c4ZHFuamRsWEE)

Comment: Thanks, Jacob! This looks like an even better solution. I can't quite get it to work, though, cf. [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvJ87ZzefkStdDh6UzBpR0hsdWRadEdjWUpyNzZsNUE&usp=sharing).

Comment: @Nagel If you share a doc with us, we will make it work!

Comment: Ok. I have now made [my example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvJ87ZzefkStdDh6UzBpR0hsdWRadEdjWUpyNzZsNUE#gid=0) editable by anyone.

Comment: @Nagel Made some changes. Set column A to plain text. Otherwise the `SPLIT` function doens't work. Added a hyphen ("-") to the SPLIT as well.

Comment: Marvelous! Great to see that it's working.