# How to filter and sort according to a preset order for a Query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

In Google Sheets, I'm using a query to pull all my data from different tabs into one master sheet. And now I'm wondering how to sort the data according to a preset order. The order I want to sort to is something like this:

1-2 months
2-3 months
3-4 months
...up to 11-12 months

Right now when I sort 1-2months comes first, followed by 11-12 months.

Is there a simple way to sort these fields according to a preset order?

Comment: That sort of sort indicates that you are doing it on textual values. With no other (and better) specifications about your file I can only recommend you name them: `01`-02 months `02`-03 months `03`-04 months ... up to `11`-12 months

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort cells with text and numbers correctly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74150/how-to-sort-cells-with-text-and-numbers-correctly)

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly adapt the formula to make it work. It shows up a 'Formula Parse Error'

Comment: share your experience with us, post the link to your file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, share a link to a spreadsheet with some realistic data already entered, as well as your expected result (hand-entered). Formulas are written around specifics, and right now, we don't have enough to build upon.